# Is there a way to increase the height of view controller in storyboard in Xcode 6?

Tags: io, xcode6

A have many subviews in my view controller which I design in storyboard with autolayout. Those subviews don't fit the view controller box. I can only make those subviews fit view controller if I make them smaller than their actual width/height constraint value. But if I do that - it shows "misplaced view" warnings. I already have 25 of those and it starts to get messy.

It would be handy if I could increase the height of this view controller box in the storyboard. Is it possible?

I am talking only about designing in the storyboard, not the actual view controller erin the app.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Select the view controller and open size inspector in the right column (5th icon). There's an option called "Simulated size". Change it to freeform and you'll be able to set any size you want.